# Exported method `TryRuntime_on_runtime_upgrade` is not found

Tags: runtime-upgrade, parachain-collator, migration, error, upgrade

```
cargo run --features try-runtime try-runtime \ 
    --execution Native \
    --chain dev \
    on-runtime-upgrade \
    live \
    --uri ws://xxxxxxxx
```

I implemented try-runtime according to the standard, but the following error keeps appearing, what is the reason for this?
error info

```
Error: Input("failed to execute TryRuntime_on_runtime_upgrade: Other: Exported method TryRuntime_on_runtime_upgrade is not found")
```

Comment: [node cargo.toml](https://github.com/listenofficial/listen-parachain/blob/main/node/tisten/Cargo.toml)

Comment: ``` cargo run --features try-runtime try-runtime \
    --execution native-else-wasm \
    --chain test \
    on-runtime-upgrade \
    live \
    --uri ws://47.108.199.133:9947```

Comment: [https://github.com/listenofficial/listen-parachain/blob/main/runtime/tisten/src/lib.rs#L1449](https://github.com/listenofficial/listen-parachain/blob/main/runtime/tisten/src/lib.rs#L1449)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I mean, according to this [document](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/tools/try-runtime/), the try-Runtime code written does not run

Comment: @junyuanwei did you discover what the issue was?

Answer (score 1):

*[Related to the when the question was asked](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11718)*

The runtime against which you are running is not compiled with --features try-runtime. If you are on latest version, read the docs here: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/try_runtime_cli/index.html#examples